# JUnit Test for Android app

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm new to Java and Android and am trying to create a JUnit test for the add, subtract, multiply, and division functions in this class. However, I'm having trouble because the app uses a switch case instead of methods for the calculations. I don't know how to set up the test to call the switch case functions as you would normally call each method.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etNum1;
EditText etNum2;

Button btnAdd;
Button btnSub;
Button btnMult;
Button btnDiv;

TextView tvResult;

String oper = "";
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)        findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    // find the elements
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    etNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    etNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum2);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    btnMult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMult);
    btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);

    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    // set listeners
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttononClick(view);
        }
    });
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttononClick(view);
        }
    });
    btnMult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttononClick(view);
        }
    });
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttononClick(view);
        }
    });



}

 public void buttononClick(View v) {
   /**
    * Description: This method is the function that occurs when a user        clicks one of the buttons in the simple calculator
    * Author: Randy Adkins
    * Date: September 25, 2016
    */
    float num1 = 0;
    float num2 = 0;
    float result = 0;

    // check if the fields are empty
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum1.getText().toString())
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum2.getText().toString())) {
        return;
    }

    // read EditText and fill variables with numbers
    num1 = Float.parseFloat(etNum1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Float.parseFloat(etNum2.getText().toString());

    // defines the button that has been clicked and performs the corresponding operation
    // write operation into oper, we will use it later for output
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            oper = "+";
            result = num2 + num2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnSub:
            oper = "-";
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnMult:
            oper = "*";
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiv:
            oper = "/";
            result = num1 / num2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // form the output line
    tvResult.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + result);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
       TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Personally I would split out your calculation functionality into its own class that does not rely on Android components (e.g. pass in `num1` and `num2` as parameters, return `result`). This would allow you to create standard JUnit tests that are a lot quicker than Connected Android Tests. Read up about Unit Testing here - https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the switch-case part to some method. Pass the required parameter and then return the result.

```
public float getValue(int id, float num1, float num2){
    float result = 0.0;
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.btnAdd:
        oper = "+";
        result = num2 + num2;
        break;
    case R.id.btnSub:
        oper = "-";
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case R.id.btnMult:
        oper = "*";
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case R.id.btnDiv:
        oper = "/";
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return result;
}
```